# The web application [VehicleRouting] appears to have started a thread named [drools-worker-4] but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, optaplanner

I build a vehicle routing web application using optaplanner. When I tried to deploy my web application to a tomcat 8 server, and tried to run it from my web browser, it produces a warning in my tomcat log file. The log said something about my web application started a thread and failed to stop it, and probably will create a memory leak. 
I have write a destroy method where my ExecutorService object will call shutdown method to make sure every thread it started was terminated. Here is my code :

```
public class OptimizerService implements IOptimizerService {
    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public synchronized Boolean startSolving() throws Throwable {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        ...
    }

    ...
    // other methods 
    ...

    @PreDestroy
    public synchronized void destroy() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But why I still got those warning in tomcat log? 
Here is the tomcat log :

```
09-Jun-2017 08:25:56.377 WARNING [http-nio-18081-exec-295] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [VehicleRouting] appears to have started a thread named [drools-worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

**`executor.shutdownNow();` interrupts the threads**, but `executor.shutdown();` does not. That latter just waits until the tasks are finished, good luck if you have a 2h solver running...

If the `Solver` detects that its thread is interrupted, it terminates (pretty much the same as a normal `Termination`), which in turns calls `KieSession.dispose()`. I presume `dispose()` takes care of any drools spawned threads.

That's the theory at least :)

Comment: Might also just be caused by [this jira fixed for 7](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1156).

Comment: So do you mean I should use executor.shutdownNow() instead executor.shutdown() ? If I use executor.shutdownNow(), it will make the solver automatically detects the thread interruption, and will terminates and dispose all drools spawned threads right?

Comment: I have use executor.shutdownNow(); but tomcat server still produce the same error in the log file. Is this a dangerous problem?.. Any other idea how to solve this?..